# Form submissions that require users ID#

Tags: forms, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm new to asking questions here, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm managing a Wordpress website for an organization that is going to have an upcoming election of board members and they'd like to do it online using a form. They currently use Ninja Forms.

In order to verify each form submission they want to see if it is possible to only accept forms after the person enters a serial number that will be assigned to them, or possibly the ID# that Wordpress automatically assigns to users.

Any thoughts on accomplishing this? Or the best place to track down a developer to help accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to touch code, you could create a page whose content only logged-in users can see. That way only valid users can see the form. You'd want to look for a content restriction / membership plugin to handle the protection of that page. You can set a field - perhaps their email address - to only accept unique submissions, so if someone tried to vote twice, Ninja Forms would prevent them from even submitting a duplicate.

If you want to touch code, you could register a hidden field in your form (see https://paulund.co.uk/register-hidden-fields-ninja-forms but instead of including user IP you'd use `get_current_user_id()` to capture their auto-generated WP ID). You would then also want to create a child theme and apply a template to that specific page to hide the form if the current user is not logged in.